# VB.NET Ftp error 503 Not Logged In - How to fix it?

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I am using visual basic 2010, and I am creating a version checking Sub.

It was working fine an hour ago,

but now it suddenly returns an error "503 Not logged in "

```
Public Sub MainChecking()
    Dim filename As String = "ftp://demonkinglbh.bplaced.net/VerionInfo.txt"
    Dim ftpReq As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(filename), FtpWebRequest)
    ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
    ftpReq.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("demonkinglbh", "RAPTORMAN2")
    ftpReq.UsePassive = False
    Dim ftpResp As FtpWebResponse = ftpReq.GetResponse
    Dim ftpRespStream As Stream = ftpResp.GetResponseStream

    Dim reader As StreamReader
    reader = New StreamReader(ftpRespStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    Label2.Text = reader.ReadToEnd.ToString
    reader.Dispose()
    If Label2.Text = MainController.Version Then
        Label1.Text = lines(43)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(150)
        Main.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox(lines(44))
        UpdateTool()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You'd have to look at the other end of the wire.  I can easily get to it without being logged-in so consider just removing the Credentials property assignment.

Comment: Your code works for me. So I assume it was just a temporarily problem (you might have been banned temporarily for trying too many times).